# Move files to trash using NSWorkspace doesn't allow restore

Tags: cocoa

From a cocoa app I need to move files to trash and this is enough simple using NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation but the file on trash can't be restore to its original position.

The restore seems to work only from Finder.

I need a solution using standard API and running on Snow Leopard 10.6.x or above

Comment: It seems recent OSX versions fixed that. I can put back files on 10.10.5, using recycleURLs.

Comment: I've tried recycleURLs:, trashItemAtURL:, performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation and even the older FSPathMoveObjectToTrashSync. None of them make "Put Back" in Finder's Trash work, at least not on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 4):

In 10.8+ `NSFileManager` `trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:` moves file to trash with the "Put Back" option (it also moves the file synchronously and doesn't emit sounds).

There's no good method for older systems, but you can use new method where it's available and have fallback for older systems:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
          respondsToSelector:@selector(trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:)]
```

Comment: I'm on 10.8.5 now and I confirm that after trashItemAtURL function there is NO option "Put Back"

Comment: @dev_null Is that new in 10.8.5? I'm on 10.8.4 and "Put Back" works for me (I've tested it extensively for [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com))

Comment: I have no 10.8.4 now. If what you say is true, then there is some opaque thing which has to be respected in order to see the menu item. Surely I will share if found what is it.

Answer (score 1):

I just now discovered that if I pass a valid NSURL ** instead of nil as the resultingItemURL: parameter to NSFileManager trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:, then I can put back the files from trash.  Even though I do nothing with the resultingItemURL afterwards.

Comment: Does not seem to be true for 11.2

Answer (score -1):

Didn't test it, but maybe this method will do it:

```
recycleURLs:completionHandler:
```

At least the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW6) says "Moves the specified URLs to the trash in the same manner as the Finder."

Best regards,
Stephan.

Comment: recycleURLs moves to trash but doesn't allow to restore element to original position, so it's behavior is different from Finder